# Convert list of tuples to structured numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of `Num_tuples` tuples that all have the same length `Dim_tuple`

```
xlist = [tuple_1, tuple_2, ..., tuple_Num_tuples]
```

For definiteness, let's say `Num_tuples=3` and `Dim_tuple=2`

```
xlist = [(1, 1.1), (2, 1.2), (3, 1.3)]
```

I want to convert `xlist` into a structured numpy array `xarr` using a user-provided list of column names `user_names` and a user-provided list of variable types `user_types`

```
user_names = [name_1, name_2, ..., name_Dim_tuple]
user_types = [type_1, type_2, ..., type_Dim_tuple]
```

So in the creation of the numpy array,

```
dtype = [(name_1,type_1), (name_2,type_2), ..., (name_Dim_tuple, type_Dim_tuple)]
```

In the case of my toy example desired end product would look something like:

```
xarr['name1']=np.array([1,2,3])
xarr['name2']=np.array([1.1,1.2,1.3])
```

How can I slice `xlist` to create `xarr` without any loops?

Comment: `without any loops` is this possible without loops? What about list comprehension? Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, though the only thing I've gotten to work are hard-coding solutions that first involve xlist --> np.array(xlist).

Comment: For example, xtemp = np.array(xlist), and x1=np.array(xtemp[:,1]), this creates a numpy array of one-element tuples, which is not what I want. I can't seem to get the slicing right, that's the entire problem. Should be simple, I realize.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A list of tuples is the correct way of providing data to a structured array:

```
In [273]: xlist = [(1, 1.1), (2, 1.2), (3, 1.3)]

In [274]: dt=np.dtype('int,float')

In [275]: np.array(xlist,dtype=dt)
Out[275]: 
array([(1, 1.1), (2, 1.2), (3, 1.3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8')])

In [276]: xarr = np.array(xlist,dtype=dt)

In [277]: xarr['f0']
Out[277]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [278]: xarr['f1']
Out[278]: array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3])
```

or if the names are important:

```
In [280]: xarr.dtype.names=['name1','name2']

In [281]: xarr
Out[281]: 
array([(1, 1.1), (2, 1.2), (3, 1.3)], 
      dtype=[('name1', '<i4'), ('name2', '<f8')])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#filling-structured-arrays

Comment: This got me to exactly where I started from.

Answer (score -1):

hpaulj's answer is interesting but horrifying :)

The modern Pythonic way to have named columns is to use `pandas`, a highly popular package built on top of `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd

xlist = [(1, 1.1), (2, 1.2), (3, 1.3)]

# Cast name1 to int because pandas' default is float
df = pd.DataFrame(xlist, columns=['name1', 'name2']).astype({'name1':int})
print(df)
```

This gives you a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html), `df`, which is the structure you want:

```
   name1  name2
0      1    1.1
1      2    1.2
2      3    1.3
```

You can do all kinds of wonderful things with this, like slicing and various operations.

For example, to the create the `xarr` dictionary requested in the original question:

```py
>>> xarr = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in df.to_dict(orient='list').items()}
>>> xarr
{'name1': array([1, 2, 3]), 'name2': array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3])}
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the original question, and suggests using a much larger and bloated package that can be avoided using the accepted answer.

Comment: OK fwyzard, good point; I have added a one-liner to convert to the exact format requested in the original question. Also, pandas' "bloat" could be considered a feature, not a bug: unless you have a very good reason, it is probably better to rely on a well-supported package rather than to try to "roll your own" solution to a basic data transformation task.

Comment: Hi Michael, I do agree with reusing well-supported software.

However `import pandas` takes more than 0.5 seconds on an dual AMD EPYC 7763 server... for a _simple_ transformation, that's likely more than the time taken by the operation itself :-(

I'd be much happier with pandas if it could be used in a more modular way.