# How to change list of tuples to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame as below:

```
  id      points
0  1      (-2.3, 7)
1  1      (-5, 7)
2  1      (-6.9, 5)
3  2      (2, 5.9)
4  2      (-0.3, -8)
```

I am trying to use groupby id and get a numpy 2darray like below:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["id"])["points"]\
          .apply(lambda x : np.array(x.values)).reset_index()
```

This works but it changes to list of tuples (like below), how to change to numpy array ? OR what I am considering as list of tuples is actually a numpy 2d array?

```
  id   points
0  1   [ (-2.3, 7), (-5,7), (-6.9,5) ]
1  2   [ (2, 5.9), (-0.3, -8) ]
```

Comment: A terrific answer here may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176949/convert-list-of-tuples-to-structured-numpy-array

Comment: Actually, those are *arrays* they just look like lists when printed inside a `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: My answer assumes you wanted a 2D numpy array instead of a numpy array of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is a numpy array of tuples, then that's what you've already got:

```
In [8]: df.groupby('id').points.apply(np.asarray).values
Out[8]: 
array([array([(-2.3, 7), (-5, 7), (-6.9, 5)], dtype=object),
       array([(2, 5.9), (-0.3, -8)], dtype=object)], dtype=object)
```

However, if you want to convert your output to a 2D array instead of an array of tuples, read on.

---

**Option 1**

Convert `points` before groupby (you can manage without a `lambda`):

```
In [785]: df.points = df.points.apply(np.array); df
Out[785]: 
   id        points
0   1   [-2.3, 7.0]
1   1       [-5, 7]
2   1   [-6.9, 5.0]
3   2    [2.0, 5.9]
4   2  [-0.3, -8.0]

In [787]: df.groupby('id').points.apply(np.asarray)
Out[787]: 
id
1    [[-2.3, 7.0], [-5, 7], [-6.9, 5.0]]
2             [[2.0, 5.9], [-0.3, -8.0]]
```

**Option 2**

Convert `points` after groupby (you'll need a `lambda` for this):

```
In [796]: df.groupby('id').points.apply(lambda x: np.array(list(map(list, x))))
Out[796]: 
id
1    [[-2.3, 7.0], [-5.0, 7.0], [-6.9, 5.0]]
2                 [[2.0, 5.9], [-0.3, -8.0]]
```

Once done, call `df.reset_index` to get your desired output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ahahaha yes. The last time I restarted was when the prompt read 2k something. Will do.

Comment: @piRSquared Seems familiar? :p Haha, I think you know where I picked it up from.